# Run two window locations using URL queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have a hyperlink in my android app run a URL query and load a second destination with an onclick delay. The purpose of this is because i need to clear saved listings via url query, and then run another query to view the saved listings. For example:

```
<a href="/browse?task=item.clearSaved" onclick="setTimeout(window.location.href='/browse?task=item.viewSaved', 1000)" class="cd-button"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Clear Saved</a>
```

I have also tried things like double url queries which does not work

href="/browse?task=item.clearSaved?task=item.viewSaved"

href="/browse?task=item.clearSaved&task=item.viewSaved"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated to achieve my goal, if it is not possible thank you any way in advance.

Comment: Once you redirect to a different page, the current page has no control over the browser anymore. You're gonna have to do the second redirect on the /browse page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax call first and on success call `window.location.href`

```
var clearAndView = function(){
  $.ajax({
     url:"/browse?task=item.clearSaved",
     success: function(){
       window.location.href = "/browse?task=item.viewSaved";
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: Only the second url for viewing is working. This is how i formated it since your format was not working.

function clearAndView(){
jQuery.ajax({
     url:"browse?task=item.clearSaved",
     success: function(){
       window.location.href = "browse?task=item.viewSaved";
    } 
 });
}

Comment: Thank you, I am getting SyntaxError: missing } after property list, then if i add a "," after the url i am getting clearAndView not defined.

Comment: Are you not familiar with javascript?

Comment: Yes, now it is repeating the same issue as i posted earlier after reformating. It is now only viewing the listings in a loop without clearing them with the initial url parameter.

Comment: actually im sorry... Testing on the web browser it is not working however in the android simulator it is strange.... I will mark as correct :D thanks so much!!